# Magmi Root Category Creation

Tags: magento-1.9, category, magmi

I have one store (base) and I need to create another root category to test a new strucutre out so my plan was to create a new `Root Category` and then tell magmi to import into that... No such luck.

I've created a new root category called Testing.

Here is a sample of the Data.

```
sku,categories
12345, [Testing]/Level1;;[Testing]/Level1/Level2;;[Testing]/Level1/Level2/Level3
```

Every time I try and import this, I get this error:

`On the fly category creator/importer v0.2.5 - Cannot find site root with names : Testing,Testing,Testing`

Can anyone help me out with this one?

Answer (score 0):

This should be like

sku,categories

12345, [Default Category]/Testing/Level1;;[Default Category]/Testing/Level1/Level2;;[Default Category]/Testing/Level1/Level2/Level3

you have to pass Root category in [] .

Answer (score 0):

Please Update Like this

sku,categories

```
12345, [Default Category]/Testing/Level1;;[Default Category]/Testing/Level1/Level2;;[Default Category]/Testing/Level1/Level2/Level3
```

First,you have to pass Root category in [] .